# How to prevent data from Interception?

Tags: encryption, xss, session-management, json

I am a web developer. A few days ago, I used Burp, to intercept facebook's official App over network, by setting up proxy. I noticed that the data was encrypted. While I have been using `Json` to communicate, I am wondering, how can I encode my `Json` string as well. so that, I can avoid, `Session Hijacking` and `XSS`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. The title talks about interception, but your question is about encoding. Are you concerned about encryption during transmission? XSS attacks? Other?

Comment: @NeilSmithline, I want to encrypt all my data during its transmission so that even if user, intercepts the requests, he/she is still not able to get anything out of it.

Comment: Can't you use SSL? That is what is typically used for on the wire encryption

Comment: @NeilSmithline, please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look at the next moments and pick something that will fit your requirements for a particular task :

- a PKI to do the job of Key distribution. Pre-seed your app with your CA public key and with a client key to connect to your HTTPS. Make sure to maintain an app package integrity as hard as possible, i.e. checksums... In Microsoft Store agreement I've seen a part that allows MS to remove all digital signatures and sign a result themselves. Keys can be tampered in such a step, so beware.
- Tor or I2P for routing pattern detection avoiding. Not just *where* your app connects, but also *how* the connection behaves, i.e. network connection flow, address list, e.t.c. can be ised to cherrypick your app's traffic and divert it through malicious filters.
- FreeNet and ZeroNet for publishing read-only static for your app : if your content is signed and the signature can be verified - it is also distributed in a non-centralized way, so it's useless to "ban" or divert a traffic to "mothership node(s)"

Layering-up theese levels of protection will actually let you just pass-through your JSON communication through this secure pipe. Feel free to ask further questions - I'll be glad to help